# How to use pandas rolling_sum with sliding windows

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate the sum or other calculation with sliding windows.
For example I would like to calculate the sum on  the last 10 data point from current position  where A is True.
Is there a way to do this ?
With this it didn't return the value that I expect.

I put the expected value and the calculation on the side.

Thank you

```
In [63]: dt['As'] = pd.rolling_sum( dt.Val[ dt.A == True ], window=10, min_periods=1)

In [64]: dt
Out[64]:
    Val     A     B  As
0     1   NaN   NaN NaN
1     1   NaN   NaN NaN
2     1   NaN   NaN NaN
3     1   NaN   NaN NaN
4     6   NaN  True NaN
5     1   NaN   NaN NaN
6     2  True   NaN   1  pos 6 = 2
7     1   NaN   NaN NaN
8     3   NaN   NaN NaN
9     9  True   NaN   2  pos 9 + pos 6 = 11
10    1   NaN   NaN NaN
11    9   NaN   NaN NaN
12    1   NaN   NaN NaN
13    1   NaN  True NaN
14    1   NaN   NaN NaN
15    2  True   NaN   3  pos 15 + pos 9 + pos 6 = 13
16    1   NaN   NaN NaN
17    8   NaN   NaN NaN
18    1   NaN   NaN NaN
19    5  True   NaN   4  pos 19 + pos 15 = 7
20    1   NaN   NaN NaN
21    1   NaN   NaN NaN
22    2   NaN   NaN NaN
23    1   NaN   NaN NaN
24    7   NaN  True NaN
25    1   NaN   NaN NaN
26    1   NaN   NaN NaN
27    1   NaN   NaN NaN
28    3  True   NaN   5 pos 28 + pos 19 = 8
```

This almost do it

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dt = pd.read_csv('test2.csv')

dt['AVal'] = dt.Val[dt.A == True]
dt['ASum'] = pd.rolling_sum( dt.AVal, window=10, min_periods=1)
dt['ACnt'] = pd.rolling_count( dt.AVal, window=10)

In [4]: dt
Out[4]:
    Val     A     B  AVal  ASum  ACnt
0     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     0
1     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     0
2     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     0
3     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     0
4     6   NaN  True   NaN   NaN     0
5     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     0
6     2  True   NaN     2     2     1
7     1   NaN   NaN   NaN     2     1
8     3   NaN   NaN   NaN     2     1
9     9  True   NaN     9    11     2
10    1   NaN   NaN   NaN    11     2
11    9   NaN   NaN   NaN    11     2
12    1   NaN   NaN   NaN    11     2
13    1   NaN  True   NaN    11     2
14    1   NaN   NaN   NaN    11     2
15    2  True   NaN     2    13     3
16    1   NaN   NaN   NaN    11     2
17    8   NaN   NaN   NaN    11     2
18    1   NaN   NaN   NaN    11     2
19    5  True   NaN     5     7     2
20    1   NaN   NaN   NaN     7     2
21    1   NaN   NaN   NaN     7     2
22    2   NaN   NaN   NaN     7     2
23    1   NaN   NaN   NaN     7     2
24    7   NaN  True   NaN     7     2
25    1   NaN   NaN   NaN     5     1
26    1   NaN   NaN   NaN     5     1
27    1   NaN   NaN   NaN     5     1
28    3  True   NaN     3     8     2
```

but need to NaN for all the value in ASum and ACount where A is NaN
Is this the way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you just doing a sum, or is this a simplified example for a more complex problem?

If it's just a sum then you can use a mix of `fillna()` and the fact that `True` and `False` act like 1 and 0 in `np.sum`:

```
In [8]: pd.rolling_sum(dt['A'].fillna(False), window=10,
                       min_periods=1)[dt['A'].fillna(False)]
Out[8]: 
6     1
9     2
15    3
19    2
28    2
dtype: float64
```

Comment: yes the value 1 is just for simplicity.  It can be any number > 0. I reedit the sample data.  Thank you